# Control flow of this try-catch-finally block

Tags: c#, exception

I'm a c++ developer who is going through some C# that he doesn't understand.  The format of the code is basically:

```
bool method (params)
{
    ...
    try
    {
         Do Some Stuff with some manual throws and some method calls;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
     if (e is SomeSpecificTypeOfException)
          throw e;
     else
          return false;
    }
    finally
    {
         Do Some More Stuff;
    }
    ...
    return true;
}
```

How should I interpret this code?  Fellow developer says he's never seen this type of usage but is probably "always do finally just before exiting method" which would mean that the catch then rethrow does the finally before throwing e above it and the catch/return returns false after reaching the end of the finally.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, the `finally` is always executed just before exiting the method (whether via `return` or `throw`).

Comment: Here is a link to exception handling documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173162.aspx

Comment: Important to note that rethrowing e like that will break your stack trace, it would be better to have `throw;` which retains the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

If something goes wrong in the try, it will do the catch. The finally always executes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dszsf989.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well, `finally` in C# is in some way similar to destructors of stack-based object in C++ that are called automatically when an exception is thrown.

Alternatively,

```
try { a; } 
catch { b; }   // Might have multiple catches...
finally { c; }
```

is essentially equivalent to:

```
try
{
    try { a; } 
    catch { b; }  // All catch clauses would be here...
}
catch
{
     c;      // code that was in finally block.
     throw;  // rethrow same exception
}
```

In C++, one would write code like this:

```
class Cleaner { ~Cleaner() { c(); } };

void method() 
{
    Cleaner cleaner;
    try { a(); }
    catch(...) { b(); }

    // Thus c(); would be executed before leaving method
 }
```

Obviously, this can be made more generic with lambdas...